# Why Can't I catch Groovy's MissingMethodException?

Tags: grails, groovy, exception, missingmethodexception

I am working on exception handling in one of my static methods. I've discovered the MissingMethodException (through trial and error) but when I write code to catch it, Grails 2.3.11 is ignoring the catch block. Not even the default Exception is being used. Why isn't the exception being caught?

```
package utility

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

class DateUtility {

    static String getGrailsDefaultDate(String datetm) {
        def format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMddHHmmss")
        try{
            def date = format.parse(datetm)
            date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").format(date)
            datetm = date.toString()
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException iae){
            datetm = "An error occured retrieving the date"
        }

        catch(NullPointerException npe){
            datetm = "A date was not provided"
        }
        catch(java.text.ParseException pe){
            datetm = "Unparseable date"
        }
        catch(groovy.lang.MissingMethodException mme){
            datetm = "A missing method occured"
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            datetm = "default exception"
        }

        return datetm
    }

}
```

And here is the call which should throw the missing method exception:

`DateUtility.getGrailsDefaultDate(1)`

Comment: You call that outside the method above. Have you tried catching it outside of the method above (ie: where you call it?)

Comment: @tim_yates that did work. The line in my method that would throw the MissingMethodException is `def date = format.parse(datetm)` where you replace datetm with a 1. Why can I not catch the exception inside my DateUtility class?

Comment: With the integer `1`?  Or the String `"1"`?

Comment: integer 1 like in OP.

Comment: And you're ___sure___ the exception is being thrown at `format.parse(datetm)`? You specify that `getGrailsDefaultDate` takes a string

Comment: I just tested it again. Moving the code inside a method makes the exception get thrown at the actual call to `getGrailsDefaultDate` because like you said, `getGrailsDefaultDate`takes a String. I changed the parameter type to `def`. Now the exception actually gets thrown at `format.parse(datetm)` and this time I am able to catch it successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't the exception being caught?

Your `catch` block is only going to catch exceptions that are thrown from your `try` block.  There are no expressions in your `try` block which are going to throw a `MissingMethodException`, so your `catch` block that catches `MissingMethodException` isn't going to be invoked.  This all looks to be working as designed.

If you put your `DateUtility.getGrailsDefaultDate(1)` inside of a `try` block that has a `catch` block associated with it which catches `MissingMethodException`, then that `catch` block would be invoked.

Try this...

```
class DateUtility {

    static String getGrailsDefaultDate(String datetm) {
        def format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMddHHmmss")
        try{
            def date = format.parse(datetm)
            date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").format(date)
            datetm = date.toString()
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException iae){
            datetm = "An error occured retrieving the date"
        }

        catch(NullPointerException npe){
            datetm = "A date was not provided"
        }
        catch(java.text.ParseException pe){
            datetm = "Unparseable date"
        }
        catch(groovy.lang.MissingMethodException mme){
            datetm = "A missing method occured"
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            datetm = "default exception"
        }

        return datetm
    }

    static void main(args) {
        try {
            DateUtility.getGrailsDefaultDate(1)
        } catch (MissingMethodException mme) {
            println 'I Caught The Exception!'
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are right Jeff. I assume tim_yates did not feel like they needed to post an official answer so I'll accept yours since you went through the trouble. I actually **do** want the exception to be caught inside the method so I changed the parameter type from `String` to `def`. Thank you.

Comment: I had not read the comments so didn't see that Tim had responded there.  If he posts the same answer, move the accept to him.  I don't really care about getting the green check.  I was trying to help.